# Floating Action Button not overlapping Bottom Sheet

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the problem that my Floating Action Button is not overlapping over the Bottom Sheet in a Coordinator Layout. How can I solve this problem? The underlying layout is a Map Fragment.

[The layout looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXr21.png)

The XML looks a following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButtonAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end|top"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_48dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="4dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_bottom_sheet">

        <!-- include bottom sheet -->
        <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_peek" />

        <!-- include main content -->
    <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Probably, the elevation attribute of your bottom sheet is higher than the FAB.

Comment: did you tried using framelayout instead of linearlayout ?

Comment: I don’t think it’s ever going to work with this layout. The FAB should not be part of the bottom sheet.

Comment: A frame layout doesn't solve the problem and i think the elevation is only for the shadow.

Comment: just move your FAB to the bottom of the parent layout or below linear_layout_bottom_sheet

Comment: Moving it under the linear_layout_bottom_sheet doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try set positive marginTop at LinearLayout and remove negative one from FAB:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButtonAdd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|top"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_48dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:elevation="4dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"/>

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_bottom_sheet">

        <!-- include bottom sheet -->
        <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_peek" />

        <!-- include main content -->
        <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: This also doesn't work, [here is the image](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipPM0w6Gxo6dXiNHZWIm88BNNJQ_flCHytTKJdHfuH_DEIi8a0ps6zrfgEmaDF4PnA?key=UWpkUERHWjUteDNucWwydjVCLXVGOElHand5UmxB)

Comment: Try to set transparent background to CoordinatorLayout and white background to LinearLayout